# how to get the top storytellers user id by facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, facebook-page

I um using facebook insights to get the top story tellers. I can get their cound but cannot get the userid of that particular story teller. Can anyone know the query to get the user ID of a particular story teller?

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/140902935963424/insights/page_storytellers&access_token=[removed Gayan's access token]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no function in the Insights API which would allow you to retrieve such data.